Is there a trade-off between pruning in symbolic execution and coverage as well as the final detection performance?
A common issue in symbolic execution is path explosion. Would using pruning and other heuristic strategies lead to decreased coverage and thus affect its effectiveness?

It depends on what you mean by "pruning."
If you prune unreachable (dead) code, then no. If you prune reachable code, then yes it would. The trick is figuring out what's reachable and what isn't; which is the million dollar question in symbolic simulation. If you're entirely heuristic based, you'd have to be really "conservative" and only prune what you can determine is unreachable for sure to remain sound. But that problem itself can be as hard as the path explosion problem itself. (In a sense, it's exactly the same problem.)

What I'm curious about is a scenario: during symbolic execution, if I use some prior knowledge to determine that certain paths do not need to be executed and thus prune them, it would not actually affect the final detection results but would reduce the code coverage of symbolic execution. In other words, does this scenario make sense? That is, heuristic algorithms reduce the coverage of symbolic execution, improve efficiency, but do not affect the final detection accuracy.

If you know the pruned code is unreachable, then it wouldn’t reduce coverage at all. The standard way to define “coverage” is “reachable by some valid input sequence.” You seem to have a different definition for it though?
